# Template class variable giving segment fault when changing it

Tags: c++, templates, variables

The issue I am having is in my `set_data()` function. I am trying to have it set the `data_field` variable to `d` , the variable that is passed into the function, but I am getting segmentation fault whenever I try.

this is the function calling the class

For the test run variable `i` is an int that I am trying to add to the node data_field. `i` the int value of i is `i = 0`.

```
template<class T>
void dlist<T>::rear_insert(T i){

    dnode<T>* temp;

    temp -> set_data(i); // function call that is causing the segmentation fault

    if(tail == nullptr ){

        tail = temp;

        head = temp;

    } else {

        dnode<T>* temp1 = tail;
            
        tail -> set_next(temp);

        tail = tail -> next();

        tail -> set_previous(temp1);


    }

}
```

Here is the full code I am using for the class giving me the error

```
template<class T>
class dnode{

    public:

        dnode(T d = T(), dnode *n = NULL, dnode *p = NULL) {data = d;  next = n; previous = p;}

        void set_data(T d){
            

            data_field = d; //The line that gives 
                            //segmentation fault
            
        }

        void set_next(dnode *n){next_field = n;}

        void set_previous(dnode *p){previous_field = p;}

        T data()const {return data_field;}

        dnode* next() const {return next_field;}

        dnode* previous() {return previous_field;}

    private:
        T data_field;
        dnode* next_field;
        dnode* previous_field;

};
```

I have used cout to check if it was recieving the correct data and it was able to print the correct data to the file. the issue is with `data_field = d`. I have looked over other sources and they have set up the code like I have, I am not sure why I am getting segmentation fault.

```
 void set_data(T d){

            cout << d;

            //data_field = d; 
            
 }
```

it out puts `0` which is the correct value for d. Uncommenting `data_field = d` causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code example. Without more context, I assume `dnode` you're calling `dnode->set_data` with is `null`.

Comment: @Darius How would I initialize a template variable to a default value so it would not be `null`?

Comment: In this situation, you'd need to initialize `temp` to be pointing to something valid. The simplest is to do `auto temp = new dnode<T>*();`.

Comment: @Darius Thanks for the help, that got my code working

Comment: If you would turn up your compiler warnings and listen to them you would know what is wrong. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bbxeW9osM) godbolt link. It clearly states what causes your segfault. And when you fix this bug [there are still more errors](https://godbolt.org/z/6fo9fdncW) to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you'd need to initialize temp to be pointing to something valid. The simplest is to do `auto temp = new dnode<T>();`

Comment: [This does not work](https://godbolt.org/z/PnsTvf7jd) since you are getting a pointer to a pointer from your `new`. You would have to do `auto temp = new dnode<T>();` instead.